# How to make GUI in Visual C++ in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++

i am C++ programmer at a beginner level. I want to make a user interface with icons like FIle, Menu, HElp etc ( as we often see these icons in a window application ). I have chosen WIN32 application project in Visual Studio 2010 and made a graphical interface with such buttons, tabs and icons. But now how to write a code? For example, there is a icon : HELP. When a user will click on help; the helping contents should be displayed. So how to write such a code for that HELP icon. and so on.. kindly help.

How to make GUI (User Interface) in Visual C++ in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to make a pure Win32 based UI, then have a look at [theForger's](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/) tutorials, they cover all the basics, from there [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should get you where you need to go.

IMO this way is a lot of trouble, you'd do better using something like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products/), but avoid MFC like the plague, instead aim for [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/) with ATL if you need to remain with MS libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a WIN32 application, but a **MFC application**.

And then look up MFC tutorial on Google, there are some good ones available.

MFC stands for Microsoft Foundation Classes and they are designed for exactly the kind of stuff you need - Toolbars, Buttons, Tabs, etc.

Comment: But my Boss said me to choose WIN32 application.

Comment: @NabeelAnjum either way, you can still use MFC (it would have been easier if you chose MFC directly, but whatever). Just google "using mfc in win32 application"

Comment: I dont know- He just said me to make a user interface for some applciation. He further said me to use C++ and make such interface that can be run in WIndows 7 32bit as well.

Comment: I dont knw anything about it and after so much googling, posted a question here !

Comment: @NabeelAnjum so you don't need to choose a WIN32 application. MFC applications also run on Windows. I gave you the solution, no one here is actually going to build the application for you. You're the one getting paid for it. Learn and use MFC.

Comment: So, according to you, MFC is the best way to understand the windows programming.  IF so, then i am going for it. THanks a lot

Comment: @NabeelAnjum I'm saying MFC is the best choice considering your task. It allows you to create windows, toolbars, documents, buttons... basically anything you would want in a GUI application.

Comment: Why doesn't he want a Win32 application? You can have toolbars, buttons and tabs without MFC. MFC is just an abstraction of the Win32 API.

Comment: @pezcode so he doesn't reinvent the wheel. If you use MFC, it's all drag'n'drop.